# Субтитры JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, видео

Делаю проект по javaFX. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать привязку субтитров ко времени на видео?

Answer (score 4):

Как вариант использовать маркеры:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    final Label markerText = new Label();
    StackPane.setAlignment(markerText, Pos.TOP_CENTER);

    String workingDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    final File f = new File(workingDir, "../media/omgrobots.flv");

    final Media m = new Media(f.toURI().toString());

    final ObservableMap<String, Duration> markers = m.getMarkers();
    markers.put("Robot Finds Wall", Duration.millis(3100));
    markers.put("Then Finds the Green Line", Duration.millis(5600));
    markers.put("Robot Grabs Sled", Duration.millis(8000));
    markers.put("And Heads for Home", Duration.millis(11500));

    final MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer(m);
    mp.setOnMarker(new EventHandler<MediaMarkerEvent>() {
      @Override
      public void handle(final MediaMarkerEvent event) {
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
          @Override public void run() {
            markerText.setText(event.getMarker().getKey());
          }
        });
      }
    });

    final MediaView mv = new MediaView(mp);

    final StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().addAll(mv, markerText);
    root.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
      @Override
      public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        mp.seek(Duration.ZERO);
        markerText.setText("");
      }
    });

    final Scene scene = new Scene(root, 960, 540);
    final URL stylesheet = getClass().getResource("media.css");
    scene.getStylesheets().add(stylesheet.toString());

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Video Player 2");
    primaryStage.show();

    mp.play();
}
```

Comment: https://www.apress.com/gp/book/9781430268727, https://github.com/Apress/pro-javafx-2/blob/283805adf9b6416cd000ade7bbb2323bcf88cb9f/ProJavaFX2/8727_ch08code/VideoPlayer2/src/projavafx/videoplayer2/VideoPlayer2.java