# Субтитры в javaFX приложении

Tags: java, ооп, javafx, mvc

[image: часть 1]

[image: часть 2]

Делаем субтитры в архитектуре MVC, но они не работают. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем ошибка

Comment: А чем вас устроило решение на ваш предыдущий такой же вопрос?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Субтитры JavaFX](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/832678/%d0%a1%d1%83%d0%b1%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%80%d1%8b-javafx)

Comment: @Maxim , мы сделали это с использованием предыдущего ответа, но он не работает